# Provider hosted add-in configuration before first run

Tags: sharepoint-addin, configuration

I am new in sharepoint development, my first work is a provider hosted add in. When the app is installed – or before the first run – needs some configuration. How can I make a configuration page for my app?

Comment: I am actually doing some research on the same topic but using SharePoint-hosted add in. So far, the best idea is to store the settings somewhere (SharePoint property bags in my case, you could use a DB as needed) and then have the application check for them on run. If the settings are either absent or incomplete, redirect to the setting page.

Comment: Thank you. I made also hours long resourcing on the topic, and I find out the same solution. I think it would be a nice feature in the following releases of sharepoint to have the possibility of custom configuration during the app install.

Comment: In a way, if you manage to keep the load low, I think that checking every time can present some advantages. This way, you can have the configuration wizard appear **every time** the configuration is either absent or incomplete, supporting scenarios like app "upgrades", incomplete initial configuration (someone closed the browser) etc. That said, it would be nice to have some sort of integrated support from SharePoint to handle such tasks.